# Place for long stay in North India

Tags: india, rental

I am male and I need to stay with a women for long time **approx 10-20 days** in North India. Oyo, MMT, StayUncle  etc., are generally recommended for unmarried couple for one or couple of days.

Since I need to stay for long time. The hotels that allow unmarried couples may not be apt. In this case, I need to search for some independent houses or flats for rent. But it is known that families in India generally don't allow unmarried couples to take rent.

I am searching for some professional agency that provide places for long term stay. Are there any possibilities for such stay?

Comment: "North India" is an awfully large place, do you have a more specific place on mind?

Comment: @Iambshaanxy interested places are Lucknow or Agra.

Answer (score 2):

10-20 days is generally too short for renting an apartment.  However, virtually any hotel (including Oyo) would be happy to have you stay that long, and you may be able to negotiate a discounted rate.

Answer (score 1):

The better class of hotels don't have a problem with unmarried couples. I have travelled across North India in different kinds of hotels and no one has bothered us.

Comment: How many days did you stay in a hotel? I mean maximum

Comment: Deans, are you a local or obviously a tourist? I have heard it makes a difference.